# Ubuntu 16: E: Failed to fetch

Tags: ubuntu

sudo apt-get update gives me this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/0f926d2c41be3de2b8a2089364d36615abebcd1dbb4a16d2711754a6dc450a21  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/9e349f9e513f531105f32ae2eb8c2b6d4c3d69f43789ab0750dbb8e12d86520b  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Operating system is: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: How come it is unclear what I asked? I mentioned the exact action I performed on which Linux plateform. I shared the error message I got. Is there a more clear question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose for your package-sources not a mirror Server.

```
software-properties-gtk
```

and choose main server.

And `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_sublime-text-3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_*`

`sudo apt update`

Comment: You seem to know more than what your reputation reflects. It works. One last question though: why choosing a mirror server is a bad idea?

Comment: Mirror server often not  synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The usual fix is to remove the content of /var/lib/apt/lists

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

If you have limited internet trafic just remove the ones which fail.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I did what you said but I got more errors of the type : `E: Failed to fetch`